# Search button shadow

Tags: html, css

I just made my search button/icon clickable by adding a transparent button onto the input field. Not sure this is the right way to go about it but I couldn't think of anything else outside of jQuery/javascript which I'm not very experienced with. Seems to work fine except the hidden button isn't totally hidden... I've made the background transparent and said `border: none` but I can see a little shadow of it. See screenshot below and put on some glasses because it's barely noticeable. Still bugs me very much. I've looked through my stylesheet and can't find any shadow setting for inputs so unsure how to fix this.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="SearchForm" style="width: 120px; height: 29px; position: relative; top: 16px; right: 17px; padding-left: 20px;">
<form action="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/search.php" method="get" onsubmit="return check_small_search_form()">            
    <span class="add-on" style="position: absolute; top: 6px; right: 4px;"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>          
    <input type="text" class="input-small" name="search_query" id="search_query" placeholder="Search..." value="%%GLOBAL_OriginalSearchQuery%%" title="Search" />
    <input type="submit" value="" name="Search" title="Search" style="position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 0; background: transparent; border: none; width: 35px; height: 22px;" />       
</form>       
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    input[type="submit"] {
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-appearance:none;
```

}

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS please.

Comment: zoom the image, highlight the issue, the glasses didn't helped, I don't see the issue

Comment: @j08691 just posted code, duh! I could have sworn I did that when I posted. Sorry.

Comment: You want to be able to click on it, if I understand? Or does it matter? simply giving the submit button a display:none makes it possible to submit the form with enter, which is an accepted behavior. It's hard to reproduce the issue as I'm not seeing the whole style (there is more css than you posted, giving the rounded corners etc...). My guess is that this border comes from another style that you are not giving out, as I don't get the border on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/w86PQ/1/) If you have some live example, or an accurate jsfiddle/codepen it would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is I guess `border-top` of the button, or the button is not totally hidden. So you can try this out:

```
<input type="submit" />
```

And then use CSS to change the image, to the background-image for the submit button. So when you will click the form will be submitted!

```
input[type="submit"] {
  /* here, you can change the background-image
   * background-image: url('../link/to/file.png');
   */
}
```

If you really wanna get rid of it, then remove the above image, and use it as the background-image of the button. This way you won't have to worry about the button.

You can hide the button using:

```
input[type="submit"] {
 opacity:0.0; 
 filter:alpha(opacity=00); // for ie..
}
```

Also, if you provided a link to the website then we might have noticed what was causing the issue, or just the source code.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the message! I didn't realize I left out my code when I posted this. Just added it. I'm a bit confused about your css....since I want the button to disappear basically (only want the function of the button), do I want to add an image? Thanks again.

Comment: Adding the image, you can easily remove the button and this image will be shown there, just as the button was the image itself.

Comment: No, you can use the image as the background-color, and then use this `opacity:0.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=00);`

Comment: Ha! It works! Brilliant! This has been plaguing me for almost two hours! Thank you so much, truly awesome. Much much appreciated! Cheers to you.